# Sed command.Add a text at the end of each line and text as to copy from the below of each line.After that remove the added line

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

Example
A table

Sed         option           files          option

```
    Files
```

Sed         option           files          option

```
    Files
```

Sed         option           files          option

```
    Files
```

Output:

Sed     option     files     option    files

Sed     option     files     option    files

Sed     option     files     option    files

Comment: Exactly not getting what you want? can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ***guessing*** this is what you really want:

```
$ cat file
Sed         option           files          option
        Files
Sed         option           files          option
        Files
Sed         option           files          option
        Files
```

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n//' file
Sed         option           files          option        Files
Sed         option           files          option        Files
Sed         option           files          option        Files
```

Comment: Thanks jaypal for your answer